# Aligning JMenu on the right corner of JMenuBar in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenubar

So if i have a `JMenu` & `JMenuBar` defined such that:

```
jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
jMenu1.setText("About");
jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

// Finally
setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);
```

and with this the Menu "About" is aligned to the left most side of the menu bar. Is there anyway that i can align this menu on the right most side of the menu bar?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a patch available for this:

```
jMenuBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

Add this line before adding menu to menubar and your menu will come on right side of menubar. Something like:

```
.....
jMenu1.setText("About");
jMenuBar1.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue()); <-- horizontal glue
jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);
.....
```

Answer (score 5):

```
jMenuBar1.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

and don't forget alignt `JMenu` with `JMenuItem` too

```
JMenu.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Comment: does that make any difference? As without using ComponentOrienatation it works just fine?

Comment: JMenuItems are always placed inside Containers

Comment: -1 for the second part: ComponentOrientation has nothing to do with the requirement (if I understand the OP correctly, s/he has a simple layout problem ;-)

Answer (score 2):

as mKorbel said for the `JMenu` it works on a `JMenuBar` like this :

```
    jMenuBar1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your may refer to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Especially take a note on part

> by putting horizontal glue between two components in a left-to-right box, you make any extra space go between those components